# how to combine multiline macros in C with comments at the end of a line

Tags: c, comments, preprocessor

I'm having a brain cramp... is there a way in C to combine a multiline macro with a comment at each line?

e.g.

```
#define MYARRAY { \
  0.001,   //  5 mV \
  0.002,   // 10 mV \
  0.004,   // 20 mV \
  0.007,   // 35 mV \
  0.013    // 65 mV \
}
```

I need to define a list of commented array values in a header file that gets used elsewhere, and make it very human-readable.

Comment: Not sure about multiline for a Macro, but maybe you could make an enum with the mV values, and put those into one line so it's more readable? Then you could make the enum multiple lines so that it would still be nice to look at.

Comment: this generalizes to N values; right now my predecessor put a bunch of #defines like `#define coeff1 0.001`, `#define coeff2 0.002`, `#define coeff3 0.003`, etc., and it just seems *wrong* to use separate symbols when I really need an array.

Comment: What`s wrong with the original C comment `/* ... */`? But prepare for strange effects if you comment out this macro using such a comment.

Comment: @PolkaDancer: An enum with floating point constants?

Comment: You actually should not use a macro for an array initializer, but just make a `const float[] = { ... };` (or `double`) once and always use that.

Comment: Oh... right, that's a good point. Thanks Olaf! Then I don't have to muck around with that damn preprocessor.

Comment: I made that an answer. Feel free ... you know ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a comment, It seems to be an XY-problem. A macro might not be the best approach.

If you are up to a table of constants, the normal way would be just to generate an array once and use that throughout your code:

```
static const float cal_table [5] = {
    0.001,   //  5 mV
    0.002,   // 10 mV
    0.004,   // 20 mV 
    0.007,   // 35 mV
    0.013    // 65 mV
};
```

If that is only used in a single file, make it `static` as shown, else remove the `static` and add

```
extern const float cal_table[5];
```

to the header file of the module.

Note that, if this is for a small MCU (AVR/PIC) without floating point unit, you might be better off with not using `float`, but fixed-point simulated by integers (e.g. scaled to 1mV).

You can also use this as an initializer for an `auto` array variable. Make that array a `typedef`, generate the `const` as described and `memcpy` the array to the local variable as required. This is as fast as an initializer, because the compiler also has to copy that to the local array. So you use the `const` array as a template (still having a single location to change, if required) .

Comment: I usually don't accept XY-problem answers (like Humpty Dumpty, when I ask a question on SO, it means just what I choose it to say -- neither more nor less), but this is a good point.

Comment: @JasonS: I you feel better, I can remove that line. I just think it might help future readers to understand why I did provide a different solution. It was not meant as an offence (I also step into this trap from time to time).

Comment: if it's in a header file used repeatedly, does that risk creating several copies of the array? (this happens to be in a dsPIC) I am already using integers with fixed-point encoding; the example I posted was simplified.

Comment: No offense taken! Keep it in the reply, it's a valid point. I have no problem with someone pointing out the XY-problem aspect; the only time I get offended is when someone says "Oh, that's an XY-problem" and refuses to answer my question.

Comment: No. Only the _declaration_ goes into the header. That's why I provided the extra with `extern`. I'm an embedded systems engineer and used to be very conservative about memory usage. However, I do not know the dsPIC (rare device here). Just make sure it goes to Flash or you can accept the extra RAM usage (there are some tradeoffs, but not more than for the macro-approach). Even more, using a new initializer as with the macro would likely cost more memory.

Comment: ah, got it, the extern declaration goes into the header, the definition goes into a .c file.

Answer (score 11):

You can use multiline comments as a way to continue macro definitions from one line to another, instead of backslashes. As described in the C standard, §5.1.1.2/1, comments are reduced to a single space during translation phase 3, while preprocessing directives are executed in phase 4. In effect, that means that newline characters inside a multiline comment do not terminate a preprocessing directive, so you could write:

```
#define MYARRAY { /*
*/   0.001,   /*  5 mV 
*/   0.002,   /* 10 mV
*/   0.004,   /* 20 mV
*/   0.007,   /* 35 mV
*/   0.013    /* 65 mV
*/ }
```

Note that line continuations (backslash newline) are removed in phase 2, before comments are recognized as such. So the problem with using C++-style `//` comments is not that the comment includes the backslash; rather it is that the lines are first concatenated and then the comment extends to the end of the concatenated lines.

Comment: A *fantastic* answer! It also helped me get around coding standards which forbid  multi-line pre-processor macros ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this, but not with C++ style // comments.  Try it with traditional /*  */ C comments.  The C++ comments comment out the rest of the line, including the backslash.

Comment: Erik: The solution works, but the explanation is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite what you are asking for. Without comments, but still human-readable and it calculates the values for you:

```
#define MILLI_VOLT(v) (v/5000.0)

#define MYARRAY {   \
    MILLI_VOLT(5),  \
    MILLI_VOLT(10), \
    MILLI_VOLT(20), \
    MILLI_VOLT(35), \
    MILLI_VOLT(65), \
}

double a[] = MYARRAY;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the comments for other reasons (the code I posted is fake, just to get the idea across)